# Convert 8-bit PNG to 32-bit EXR using Python and Pillow

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read a PNG file, convert the 0-255 RGB values into 0.0-1.0 float values, do some manual operations on them and then save it out as a 32-bit floating point EXR file.

When loading the image and printing one of the pixel colours (before converting, using `im.getpixel((0,0))`, it shows `(57, 52, 34)`.

So then I try converting it to a 32-bit image using `im = im.convert('F')` and then print `im.getpixel((0,0))`, and it shows `51.44300079345703`.

Why is there only one value? Shouldn't it be a touple with a float for each channel?

I'm expecting it to be `(0.2235, 0.2039, 0.1333)`.

[Here is the image](http://i.imgur.com/zxsZnDj.png) if you want to play. Thanks for the help in advance :)

Comment: I don't really know anything about image processing but I don't think that mode 'F' is what you think it is. The [Pillow documentation](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes) states that you should expect one float value. My suspicion is that the value is a greyscale intensity value.

Comment: I see... reading up [here](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?2339-Converting-Linear-EXR-to-sRGB-JPEG-with-Python) and it seems like I'll need to use the OpenEXR library as well/instead.

Comment: I just found [this](http://excamera.com/articles/26/doc/intro.html). Maybe that helps as well.

Comment: The `pillow` module doesn't support EXR image format which has16-bit-per-channel  (half precision) floating point components. It's `"F"` mode has single 32-bit floating point pixel values as you discovered. The modes it supports are listed [here](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes).

Comment: I actually converted your image to greyscale in GIMP and got a value of 52 for the intensity. So, pretty close to what you got with mode F.

Comment: You could split the RGB image up into three grey-scale images and convert each of those to a separate `"F"` image which would give you what would be needed to create an EXR image yourself.